# Is it possible to load a native library in a Jetpack Compose @preview function?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, swig, android-jetpack-compose

I've begun implementing a feature on my application with Jetpack Compose.
The application uses [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) to generate code that allows me to interact with a C++ layer from Kotlin/Java. In order to use the C++ layer, I load the library like this in the app's main activity:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("{swig library name}");
}
```

When I attempt to use Jetpack Compose previews, I get the following render problem:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void {package containing swig's generated code}.swigWrappersJNI.swig_module_init()'
```

The function does use a class generated by Swig, so I'm assuming that's why this is happening.

I tried getting around this by adding the following to the preview function:

```
System.loadLibrary("{swig library name}")
```

but that just results in the following render problem:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no {swig library name} in java.library.path:
```

Does anybody know how/if I can properly link the library so that I can use Compose's preview feature as I work on this app?

Edit:

For a little more info, I've tried the following methods for loading my library:

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun ___Preview() {
    System.loadLibrary("{swig library name}");

    // Actual preview code here
}
```

```
object LibraryLoader {
    fun load() {
        System.loadLibrary("{swig library name}")
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun ___Preview() {
    LibraryLoader.load()

    // Actual preview code here
}
```

(This one was a bit of a shot in the dark. I thought the key difference could've been loading it within a `static` block, but this had no effect.)

The previews *can* be successfully deployed to a device/emulator.

I think the issue here is that the library lives in `lib/{abi}/{swig library name}.so`, so it exists when running on a device/emulator (with a supported ABI) but not for Compose previews.

What I've done to work around it is create a copy of my model classes that don't use any of Swig's generated code so I can take advantage of previews when creating the layout, then replacing them with the actual model classes for testing functionality. Definitely not a solution I'm particularly happy with but it may be the only way to use Compose previews in this type of situation.

Comment: Can you clarify, where exactly do you put `System.loadLibrary()` in your preview function? AFAIK, compose composition is asynchronous, so your library may not be yet loaded when you try to use it. You can try waiting until the library is loaded before calling any JNI stuff.
Also, I'm not sure this is gonna work in Android Studio preview at all, though it might work if you deploy the preview to the device/emulator.

Comment: I've edited my post to provide a bit more info. I don't believe it's caused by the library not yet being loaded as the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown by the `System.loadLibrary()` call itself (which is something I probably should've clarified). I think you're right that this is something that just simply won't work in Compose previews, at least not in their current state.

Comment: "The function does use a class generated by Swig" -- perhaps you should be isolating your composables from your Swig code, just as we isolate composables from making Web service calls, querying Room databases, etc.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I think this situation is a little different. I'm not using Swig to make an method calls to the C++ layer from within Composables, but one of my model classes has a property with the type being an `enum` generated by Swig from an `enum` in the C++ layer. That alone seems be enough for `{package containing swig's generated code}.swigWrappersJNI.swig_module_init()` to be called, which throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` in Android Studio's compose previewer.